# Update Multiple Columns in Access DB Using AddWithValues in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am having an issue updating multiple columns in my Access DB using the Parameters.AddWithValues.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox3.Text);

        string query = "UPDATE UserInformation SET Pin = @Pin, Email = @Email Where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID";
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not update database", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I am able to take out one of the parameters in my string and it updates just fine. Ex:

```
UPDATE UserInformation SET Pin = @Pin WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

This works fine but when I add a second to update:

```
UPDATE UserInformation SET Pin = @Pin, Email = @Email WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

it does not work.

This is just a small portion of my query string; I have about 8-10 items to update. Any Suggestions?

Comment: "does not work" means what? What error or unexpected behaviour do you experience? There's nothing obviously wrong with the code. I notice you're suppressing exceptions in your "catch" block and just displaying a generic error message. If you're going to do that, you need to log the exceptions so you can find the root cause of them. Right now if you get that message you have no way to know what really went wrong, which is very silly.

Comment: Related: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: It doesn't give me an exception when I run the code. It just doesn't do anything. It doesn't update my database at all. It should update these two columns where my EmployeeID is but it does not. 

I am aware I am suppressing the exception (for now that is all I want,) but that is not what I posted or need help with.

Comment: which parameter is causing the problem?  You said it works if you take one out.  Which one is the problem?  That should give you the clue right there.  My guess is your passing in an invalid value in that parameter.

Comment: I can change either one and it works fine

Comment: I know that's not what you're asking about, but it's still a bad practice which could give you problems (all very well when you're testing, but if an end- user experiences an error, they'll expect it fixing, hard if you have no record of what happened) and worth mentioning as an aside. Hence comment not answer :-). Anyway the answer below looks correct. I confess I hadn't noticed you were using OLE and not ADO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OleDbCommand` doesn't supports named parameters. So you can replace them with `?` instead. For example:

```
UPDATE UserInformation SET Pin = ?, Email = ? WHERE EmployeeID = ?
```

Of course this means that your `AddWithValue` methods now need to be in the correct order, this is why your code does not work - it is assigning the value of `textBox3.Text` (i.e. the email) to the `@EmployeeID` parameter. So, the order should be:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox2.Text);
```

And, I will reiterate this: [Please don't use `AddWithValue` at all](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: This works! I do have a question about how I should do it instead now.


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin",   OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox3.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = textBox2.Text ;

                string query = "UPDATE UserInformation SET Test = ? , LastName = ? Where EmployeeID = ? ";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                


Is this a better way of doing it?

Comment: Well you can call the parameter anything you like as long as you add them in the right order.

Comment: I guess I should have asked; how would you have written this? "Please don't use 'AddWithValue' at all"

Based off the link you showed above I put this in my code and it works  
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text

Just wondering if that is the better way or if there was another that you prefer

Comment: Read the link carefully, it suggests what you should be doing instead.

Comment: Got it...It seems that I now have it more or less that way. 

I do very very much appreciate your help!